# Can I repeat(loop) a FLOW screen Interview based on User Input?

Tags: visual-workflow, administration, configuration

I have a scenario where there are 5 screens.
On 2nd screen, The user will input a number(Repeat = x), based on that I want to repeat Interview screen 3, Interview screen 4, and Interview screen 5.

**Example**: If a user inputs **Repeat = 4**, then the flow will be like ==>
Screen1, Screen2,

First time -> Screen3, Screen4, Screen5 (back to screen 3 again)
Second time -> Screen3, Screen4, Screen5
Third time -> Screen3, Screen4, Screen5
Forth time -> Screen3, Screen4, Screen5
Finish!

Is repeat(loop) a screen functionality available? If not, can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create another variable in your flow, then at the last screen, add if logic if yourNewVar < repeat ==> add 1 to yourNewVar, and then return to screen 3.